# How do I remove the unit test run commands from the editor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, settings

I have a Java file open in Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0) that has @Test annotations on methods.  The editor shows...

```
@Test
Run | Debug
public static void myTest()
{
   ...
}
```

If I click on the `Run` or `Debug`, then the unit test starts running.

How do I remove the `Run | Debug` from the editor?

Comment: These are so-called _Code Minings_ that can be disabled in the preferences.

Comment: @howlger I searched for Code Mining in Eclipse Preferences.  I see how to disable all code minings.  How do I disable the unit test code minings?

Comment: Is this Eclipse without additional plugins or do you have [this plugin](https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining) installed?

Comment: @howlger I didn't have that plugin installed.  I do now.  This allowed me to turn off the unit test code minings.  Thanks!  Can you make this an answer?  I will accept it.

Comment: @howlger Oh wait.  Even if I disable the unit test code minings with the plugin, they still show up.